# How does one use the mapdict argument in pyexcel?

Tags: python, excel, pyexcel

I'm having some trouble with the mapdict argument in the save_to_database function in pyexcel.

It seems that I still need to have a row of column names in the beginning of my files otherwise I get an error. Does mapdict not specify the names to use for each column once they have been converted to a dictionary?

I'm very unsure of what this argument actually does...

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Look, it's simple
if you have CSV like this:

```
brand,sku,description,quantity,price
br,qw3234,s sdf sd ,4,23.5
br,qw3234,s sdf sd ,4,23.5
br,qw3234,s sdf sd ,4,23.5
br,qw3234,s sdf sd ,4,23.5
```

you don't need mapdict

but if your CSV without first row
you need it. For exmple one peace from my flask project:

```
def article_init_func(row):

    warehouse = Warehouse.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    a = Article()
    a.pricelist_id = p.id
    a.sku=row['sku']
    a.description=row['description']
    a.brand=row['brand']
    a.quantity=row['quantity']
    a.city=warehouse.city
    a.price=row['price']
    return a

map_row = ['brand', 'sku', 'description', 'quantity', 'price']

request.save_to_database(
    field_name='file', session=db.session,
    initializer = article_init_func,
    table=Article,
    mapdict=map_row)
```